# Una columna TIMESTAMP por tabla superado con NULL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Según  [la documentación oficial de **MSQL**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)no se pueden poner dos `TIMESTAMP` por tabla. Esto produce el error `error 1067`.
[image: mensaje de error 1067]

Sin embargo, si se permiten valores nulos no se produce este error.
[image: tabla sql]

¿A qué se debe que no ejecute el error? ¿Qué futuros problemas puedo tener si lo dejo así?

Parte de la creación de la Base de datos. El error se produce cuando llega a la tabla Empleados y ahí se para cuando llega a `modificado_en`, que es el segundo `Timestamp`.

```
CREATE DATABASE database
CHARACTER SET LATIN1
COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci;
USE database;

CREATE TABLE departamento(
    nombre_departamento VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE nivel_privilegios(
    nivel_privilegios INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE empleado(
    id_empleado INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nombre_empresa VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    contraseña VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    creado_en TIMESTAMP,
    modificado_en TIMESTAMP,
    fk_departamento_pertenece VARCHAR(100),
    fk_nivel_privilegios INT,   
    CONSTRAINT EMPLEADO_departamento_FK FOREIGN KEY (fk_departamento_pertenece) REFERENCES departamento(nombre_departamento),
    CONSTRAINT EMPLEADO_nivel_privilegios_FK FOREIGN KEY (fk_nivel_privilegios) REFERENCES nivel_privilegios(nivel_privilegios) 
);
```

Comment: Bueno eso de 1 columna solo aplica si tu versión de MySQL es menor a la 5.6.5, ¿qué versión usas?

Comment: Ese error puede venir de otro lado,  ¿cuando se ejecuta cuando construyes la tabla o cuando haces un insert?

Comment: Parece que funciona en Mysql8.0. Pero yo tengo 10.4.11-MariaDB y ahí da error. El error se produce cuando se construye la tabla.

Comment: Agrega ese detalle, agrega el código de como haces el create

Comment: Agregada creación de la base de datos, @BetaM

Comment: @FernandoLópez ¿hay algun motivo para que uses `timestamp` y no `datetime`?

Comment: Pues yo tengo en local la misma versión de MariaDB y con null o sin null funciona el create, posiblemente el error se derive en otro apartado, ¿qué hay de tu insert?, por cierto no deberías estar consultando para MariaDB la doc de MySQL, ser parecidos no los hace idénticos

Comment: No, En principio sería interesante dejar solo el `timestamp` al campo `modificado_en` para que se actualice automáticamente, y usar `datetime` o `date` para el otro campo.  Pero me gustaría saber si esto sucede por usar MariaDB en vez de Mysql8.0.  ¿Funcionaría con un `set global sql_mode = 'creado_en , modificado_en'`?

Comment: No se ha llegado a realizar ningún insert. Es el comienzo del proyecto. Pensaba que la doc de MariaDB era la misma que MySQL.Te aseguro que tengo la misma versión y nos disparaba ese error. He estado con el compañero un buen rato intentando adivinar el porqué. 
 Gracias por tu tiempo @BetaM

Answer (score 0):

¿Será posible que tengas el strict mode habilitado?

Podrías comprobarlo haciendo el siguiente select:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

Si lo tienes habilitado lo más probable es que no te lo permita por las directivas NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE ya que no te permitirán un valor a 0 ni una fecha, por ejemplo, de la forma: '0000-00-00'.

Podrías mirar la referencia de MySQL en el siguiente enlace:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Podrías cambiarlo con un set, en caso de tenerlo habilitado:

```
set global sql_mode = 'variable1, variable2';
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el tema de estas directivas ayuda en la solución al problema expuesto?, considera leer [answer] y explicar tu código

Comment: Lo tengo como indicas. `sql_mode
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTIO...'`.
¿Y el hecho de que no de error con valores nulos como se explica?